# python pandas: how to calculate derivative/gradient

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Given that I have the following two vectors:

```
In [99]: time_index
Out[99]: 
[1484942413,
 1484942712,
 1484943012,
 1484943312,
 1484943612,
 1484943912,
 1484944212,
 1484944511,
 1484944811,
 1484945110]

In [100]: bytes_in
Out[100]: 
[1293981210388,
 1293981379944,
 1293981549960,
 1293981720866,
 1293981890968,
 1293982062261,
 1293982227492,
 1293982391244,
 1293982556526,
 1293982722320]
```

Where *bytes_in* is an incremental only counter, and *time_index* is a list to unix timestamps (epoch).

**Objective:** What I would like to calculate is the bitrate.

That means that I will build a data frame like

```
In [101]: timeline = pandas.to_datetime(time_index, unit="s")

In [102]: recv = pandas.Series(bytes_in, timeline).resample("300S").mean().ffill().apply(lambda i: i*8)

In [103]: recv
Out[103]: 
2017-01-20 20:00:00    10351849683104
2017-01-20 20:05:00    10351851039552
2017-01-20 20:10:00    10351852399680
2017-01-20 20:15:00    10351853766928
2017-01-20 20:20:00    10351855127744
2017-01-20 20:25:00    10351856498088
2017-01-20 20:30:00    10351857819936
2017-01-20 20:35:00    10351859129952
2017-01-20 20:40:00    10351860452208
2017-01-20 20:45:00    10351861778560
Freq: 300S, dtype: int64
```

**Question:** Now, what is strange, calculating the gradient manually gives me :

```
In [104]: (bytes_in[1]-bytes_in[0])*8/300
Out[104]: 4521.493333333333
```

which is the correct value ..

while calculating the gradient with pandas gives me

```
In [124]: recv.diff()
Out[124]: 
2017-01-20 20:00:00          NaN
2017-01-20 20:05:00    1356448.0
2017-01-20 20:10:00    1360128.0
2017-01-20 20:15:00    1367248.0
2017-01-20 20:20:00    1360816.0
2017-01-20 20:25:00    1370344.0
2017-01-20 20:30:00    1321848.0
2017-01-20 20:35:00    1310016.0
2017-01-20 20:40:00    1322256.0
2017-01-20 20:45:00    1326352.0
Freq: 300S, dtype: float64
```

which is not the same as above, *1356448.0 is different than 4521.493333333333*

Could you please enlighten on what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`pd.Series.diff()` only takes the differences.  It doesn't divide by the delta of the index as well.

This gets you the answer

```
recv.diff() / recv.index.to_series().diff().dt.total_seconds()

2017-01-20 20:00:00            NaN
2017-01-20 20:05:00    4521.493333
2017-01-20 20:10:00    4533.760000
2017-01-20 20:15:00    4557.493333
2017-01-20 20:20:00    4536.053333
2017-01-20 20:25:00    4567.813333
2017-01-20 20:30:00    4406.160000
2017-01-20 20:35:00    4366.720000
2017-01-20 20:40:00    4407.520000
2017-01-20 20:45:00    4421.173333
Freq: 300S, dtype: float64
```

---

You could also use `numpy.gradient` passing the `bytes_in` and the delta you expect to have.  This will not reduce the length by one, instead making assumptions about the edges.

```
np.gradient(bytes_in, 300) * 8

array([ 4521.49333333,  4527.62666667,  4545.62666667,  4546.77333333,
        4551.93333333,  4486.98666667,  4386.44      ,  4387.12      ,
        4414.34666667,  4421.17333333])
```

Comment: Can you explain why `np.gradient` doesn't produce the same results as the first proposed answer.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `numpy.gradient` is implemented to use centered finite difference, whereas pandas `diff` uses backward finite difference by default. In other words, the numpy implementation works with the previous and next data points, whereas pandas works with the previous and current datapoints. [Numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) ; [Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html)

Answer (score 2):

A naive explanation would be that `.diff()` literally subtracts following entries while `np.gradient()` uses a central difference scheme.

Answer (score 2):

As there is no builtin `derivative` method in Pandas Series / DataFrame you can use https://github.com/scls19fr/pandas-helper-calc.

It will provide a new accessor called `calc` to Pandas Series and DataFrames to calculate numerically derivative and integral.

So you will be able to simply do

```
recv.calc.derivative()
```

It's using `diff()` under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

Or if you'd like to calculate the rate of change you can just use `df.pct_change()`

As a parameter you can enter `df.pct_change(n)`, where `n` is the lookback period assuming you have a datetime indexed dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

To get the correct time derivative, change the index of your `series`

```
def derivate(serie):
    df1 = (serie.diff() / serie.index.to_series().diff().dt.total_seconds()).dropna()
    df1.index = serie.index[0:-1]
    return df1
```

Comment: > Can you explain why np.gradient doesn't produce the same results as the first proposed answer. – Darthtrader May 5 at 9:58 np.gradient uses a 2nd order scheme while .diff() uses a 1st order scheme. This means that the results from np.gradient will be continuous as will the derivative. The results from .diff() do not have to have a continuous derivative. Essentially np.gradient gives 'smoother' results.