# plot derivative of y-axis against x-axis python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, derivative

I have the graph below, which is a result of a plot of a two-column data frame, which I'm simply plotting as

`df.plot(style='o-')`

**EDIT**

And I plot the running average of it (thanks to the help of people below) with:
`df.rolling(5).mean()`

Can I use some function from `pandas` to plot the derivative of the y-axis over the x-axis?

I've tried the solution proposed here: [python pandas: how to calculate derivative/gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41780489/python-pandas-how-to-calculate-derivative-gradient)
But it didn't work

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you would like to have may not be 'average' but 'smoothing' or 'regression', google for those terms can give you more relevent result.

As for your question, [Savitzky–Golay filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter) could be a good tool to use here, it does convolution "by fitting successive sub-sets of adjacent data points with a low-degree polynomial".

In Python you can use [scippy.signal.savgol_filter](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html) to get the smoothed points.
The derivative would be more tricky though,a workaround would be calculate the 
slope with convoluted signal(points).

Answer (score 1):

Like already explained, it seams that you want to apply same kind of filter instead of run an average (that in your case should return a number). To start, you can try a simple moving average doing:

```
df.rolling(5).mean()
```

Where 5 is the window.